# Is it possible to change a cable modem MAC address?

Tags: networking

I know the difference between a local ethernet router and a docsys modem. I want to know if it is possible to log into the cable modem and change its mac address.

My modem is a Motorola SB6120.

Comment: First off, why do you want to change it?  Secondly, cable modems, have multiple MAC addresses, which one are you wanting to change?

Comment: The gateway you have does not allow you to configure the mac address.  Even if you change it, your service provider, will still need authorize the address for you to be authorized on their network.

Comment: I want to change the MAC facing the ISP. Ramhound, I am fully aware of that.

Comment: It seems that JTAG reprogramming can be a way to go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some brief searching, it doesn't seem like it's possible to change the ISP-facing MAC without soldering wires to the SPI chip on the device's motherboard and reprogramming it via JTAG.  Seems that there is also a hacked firmware that would let you log in and change DOCSIS parameters on the fly, and also the MAC address on the fly.  This would also have to be programmed via soldering and JTAG.